# R - Web scraping and downloading multiple zip files and save the files without overwriting

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Trying to download multiple zip files using a web link. With this approach, the download files are getting overwritten since the file names are same for multiple years -

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://download.open.fda.gov/"
page <- read_html(url)

zips <- grep("\\/drug-event",html_nodes(page,"key"), value=TRUE)
zips_i<-gsub(".*\\/drug\\/","drug/",zips)
zips_ii<-gsub("</key>","",zips_i)
zips_iii<-paste0(url, zips_ii)

lapply(zips_iii, function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
```

Is there a way not to overwrite the downloaded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got so far -

```
#load the library
library(rvest)

#link to get the data from
url <- "https://download.open.fda.gov/"
page <- read_html(url)

#clean the URL
zips <- grep("\\/drug-event",html_nodes(page,"key"), value=TRUE)
zips_i<-gsub(".*\\/drug\\/","drug/",zips)
zips_ii<-gsub("</key>","",zips_i)
zips_iii<-paste0(url, zips_ii)

#destination vectors
id=1:length(zips_iii)
destination<-paste0("~/Projects/Projects/fad_ade/",id)

#file extraction
mapply(function(x, y) download.file(x,y, mode="wb"),x = zips_iii, y = destination)
```